# Get Python Matplotlib Radiobutton selection

Tags: python, matplotlib, indexing, radio-button, interactive

In Python, I can create Matplotlib Radiobuttons using code like this:

```
rb = RadioButtons(pl.axes([0.01,0.5,0.08,0.14]),('A','B','C',))
```

How do I get the index of the currently active radio button outside the callback function?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example for people to test with?

Comment: use `on_clicked` to register a call back